Нужно исправить код на Python, входные данные
Вот код, нужно сделать так чтобы я вводил данные в 2 строки
например:
4
1 2 1 2

а у меня в коде вводится так:
4
1
2
1
2

n = int(input())
a = []

count = 0
counter=0


for i in range(n):
    num = int(input())
    a.append(num)

for j in range(len(a)):
    if a[j] != -1:
        for jj in range(j + 1, len(a)):
            if a[j] == a[jj]:
                count += 1
                a[j] = -1
                a[jj] = -1
                break

print(count)

Сам код если что считает кол-во пар одинаковых чисел (он работает корректно я проверял)

a = [int(x) for x in input().split()] и весь этот цикл вообще не нужен

перестал код работать красава

@Глеб количество чисел Вы вводите в n, а затем в первом цикле на каждой итерации вводите числа. Если вы хотите ввести числа в одной строке, то Вам следует делать это до цикла. Но таким образом вы получите строку (str), а не набор чисел (int).

А что мешает вам использовать itertools, например? для вычисления количества пар. а если одинаковых чисел будет несколько пар, что тогда?

_ = input(); a = list(map(int, input().split())) Первый ввод вообще не нужен при нормальном подходе, тут он выбрасывается.

as per @andreymal
n = int(input())
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()][:n]

а дальше ваш второй цикл с проверкой пар.
